# Load iframe and target content

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, jquery-events, dom-manipulation

I have  a script that write a iframe into the page.
I want to target a link inside this iframe to have a function.
The problem is:
after the iframe has been written I use this code:

```
$('#iframe_pin').load(function () {
            $(this).contents().find('a.close').click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('.loaded').fadeOut(fade_time).remove();
            })
        })
```

and it doesn't work.
But if I put an alert after the load function, like this:

```
$('#iframe_pin').load(function () {alert('bla bla');
            $(this).contents().find('a.close').click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('.loaded').fadeOut(fade_time).remove();
            })
        })
```

it works!

Of course I cannot keep the alert in the code :)

Can anyone help me?

Comment: what's your html? can you paste an example on http://www.jsbin.com? I don't get what's `#iframe_pin` and `.loaded`, witch one is the `<iframe>`?

Comment: ifram_pin is the iframe;
loaded is a div;
with ".contents()" i target elements into the iframe, but it act like it's not fully loaded unless i put the alert right after the "load" function

Comment: so: `<div class="loaded"><iframe id="iframe_pin" ...></div>` ?

Comment: exactly, i want to target the "a.close" to close the div containing the iframe

Comment: Where is this `.load` placed? -- it should be set immediately when the DOM is ready in the parent.

Comment: it's places after the iframe is created:
create('iframe_pin', box, '576px', '500px');//this create the iframe
$('#iframe_pin').load(function ()....

Comment: is the `<iframe>` in other domain? or current domain where the parent page is?

Comment: it is in the same domain.
the weird thing is that just adding the alert everything works perfectly as i planned to make it work

Comment: With the alert.... do you think it is a timing issue? Load fires.. then some time after the contents are there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from comments you have something like:

```
<div class="loaded">
    <iframe id="iframe_pin" src="abc.html" width="100%" height="100%">
</div>
```

so, all you need to do is:

```
$("#iframe_pin").load(function() {

    // let's get the iframe source
    var iframe = $("#iframe_pin").contents();

    iframe.find("a.close").bind("click", function() {
        $(".loaded").fadeOut('slow', function() {
            // now that the FadeOut is finished, let's remove
            $(".loaded").remove();
        });
        return false; // let's prevent to jump in the click
    });
});
```

> working example at [my own space](http://balexandre.com/Stackoverflow/6263535/)

---

> [Example 2](http://balexandre.com/Stackoverflow/6263535/index.v2.html) by creating the `<iframe>` on the fly

---

> [Example 3](http://balexandre.com/Stackoverflow/6263535/index.v3.html) by creating the `<iframe>` on the fly, removing them and re-creating them

Comment: still doesn't work.
i think it's cause the iframe is written in runtime with another function

Comment: my example code works, just added a 2nd version so you see I'm as well creating the `<iframe>` on the fly.

Comment: remember to **upvote** the question if you want to thank, and make answer as correct if that's what you were after, in other words, if the answer is correct.

Comment: thnx balexandre, your post works perfectly, i have to check better my code, there should be some errors somewhere

Comment: added 3rd example where you can create `<iframe>` on the fly, remove it and recreate it again and again...

Comment: nothing to do, it's not working.
i replicated the exact structure as u did and still nothing